# Unable to upgrade SharePoint Admin Content Database

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-database, cumulative-update

I saw the following status: `"Database is up to date, but some sites are not completely upgraded."` under manage databases upgrade status. I upgraded most of the databases using upgrade database command, but the command fails when doing this for SharePoint Admin Content Database.

After following various blogs, i found that i may have to run the config wizard for this. But my question is:

1. Do i have to run this on each SharePoint servers in the farm? If yes, which server should i do on first (app or WFE or central admin server?).
2. Do i need to do iis reset on all server after the config wizard/command completes?

Answer (score 2):

After patching all servers in a SharePoint farm you must run the Config Wizard on each server one at a time. This will be true each time you patch the farm.

Note that certain patch levels have left the Admin db in that 'needs upgrade' state. Depending on what patch level you're at, there may be nothing you can do besides upgrade to the current revision.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes you have to run the config wizard on all server in the a farm one by one, I personally always start from Central admin server ( but order really does not matter, you can start any order).
2. Config wizard also perform the IIS reset during its run. You have to make sure all required app pools and IIS Sites are up and running.

Note: Patching process basically 2 steps process

- Install the bits(installation files) on all sharepoint servers in farm
- Run the config wizard on all server in farm one by one, this will also upgrade the content databases as well as other services and config dbs, and other updates which are part of the packages. If you have many databases you can run the Upgrade-spcontentdatabase before running the config wizard (this will help in saving the time). but Config wizard still required.